# How to define a simple potential in DPD for some type of beads?

Tags: lammps, coarse-grained, mesoscopic-physics

I apologize if this is off-topic and if so would be grateful for someone to point me to a relevant source of information.

Dissipative Particle Dynamics (DPD) is a quick simulation technique that clumps molecules in a fluid into "beads" of similar size that interact only through short range repulsive forces.  I want to introduce a polymer chain into the fluid simulation so I need tell the DPD package in LAMMPS that there is a specific (simple) potential between the "beads" that chain together to form the polymer. (Eventually we may make membranes as well).

The potentials that I can find on the LAMMPS site are for specific atoms, or contain too much physics for the simple  beads-in-a-chain model I am trying to construct.  Is there a package or way to enter simple potentials for DPD?

Comment: DL-MESO should(may... I don't do DPD, and haven't run DL_MESO) work for you. Here is a link to the user manual: https://www.scd.stfc.ac.uk/Pages/USRMAN.pdf

Comment: Hi Delaram. How did this go, did you find an answer? Please update us! Was the suggestion by @B.Kelly helpful? I'm trying to clean up the unanswered queue a bit since we have over 300 unanswered questions now!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.